# Refresh NotifyIcon message

Tags: wpf, notifyicon

I have this `NotifyIcon`:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon;

    private void CreateNotifyIcon()
    {
        notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon.Icon = myIcon;
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon.Text = "My app";
        notifyIcon.MouseClick += notifyIcon_MouseClick;
    }
```

So in my application i have `ProgressBar` that i want to shows it's `Value` insode my `NotifyIcon`:

```
    void notifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int val = progressBar.Value;
        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "Hi", val.ToString(), System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info);
    }
```

So is it possible to show this `Value` after every value change with out `Click` on my `NotifyIcon` again and again ? (just puut the mouse over the `NotifyIcon`and see the value changing)

Answer (score 0):

No, the system does not provide a mechanism for live updating of balloon tips. If you need to show this information evolving you will need to use some other form of UI to display the information.

Comment: Can you give me some other form of UI that do that ?

Comment: There are many different options you could use. I'm not sure I want to recommend one without knowing the details of your program. I just tried to answer the question that you asked. You asked *So is it possible to show this Value after every value change with out Click on my NotifyIcon again and again?*

Comment: I have progressbar that i want to show in balloon message and another several simple string

Comment: Like I said, I was just trying to answer the question that you asked.

Answer (score 0):

you can extend progress bar and it could provide to show value in popup.
it could be custom control or usercontrol or a kind of custom behaviour.

Comment: Can i have examples how to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem i used a timer and this code to make it update it self.

`timer1.start`
place this in button somewhere

`NotifyIcon.Text = ProgressBar1.Value.ToString & "% Scan Progress`Put this in the timer_tick